# Pull from CodeCommit in Container on ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-codecommit

I have a container running a process that depends on an application in a CodeCommit repo within my account. Is there anyway to clone a CodeCommit repo from inside a container running on ECS?

Answer (score -1):

I've never tried, but I don't see why not -- can't you just do a git clone once you've set up the IAM permissions to allow your ECS service role to access the CodeCommit Repo?

What have you tried? Did you encounter any problems?